# Join time series Cassandra tables in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have two tables (`agg_count_1` and `agg_count_2`) in Cassandra both with the same schema:

```
CREATE TABLE agg_count_1 (
  pk_1 text,
  pk_2 text,
  pk_3 text,
  window_start timestamp,
  count counter,
  PRIMARY KEY (( pk_1, pk_2, pk_3 ), window_start)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY ( window_start DESC )
```

`window_start` is a timestamp rounded to nearest 15 minutes which means its value is exactly the same in both tables however rows for some time windows may be missing.

I would like to efficiently (inner) join these two tables on the primary key to a third table with very much the same schema and store value of `agg_count_1.counter` to `counter_1` and `agg_count_2.counter` to `counter_2` columns:

```
CREATE TABLE agg_joined (
  pk_1 text,
  pk_2 text,
  pk_3 text,
  window_start timestamp,
  int counter_1,
  int counter_2,
  PRIMARY KEY (( pk_1, pk_2, pk_3 ), window_start)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY ( window_start DESC )
```

This can be done in many ways using combination of Scala, Spark and Spark-Cassandra connector features. **What is the recommended way?**

I would appreciate to hear about solutions to avoid. Joins are in general expensive but I would expect this kind of "zipping" of time series should be fairly efficient if you (actually me) don't do anything wrong.

Based on [Spark-Cassandra documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md) using `joinWithCassandraTable` sounds suboptimal because it executes a single query for every partition:

> `joinWithCassandraTable` utilizes the java drive to execute a single query for every partition required by the source RDD so no un-needed data will be requested or serialized.